# Documentation for a client/server program with OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I have a client/server program in TCP written in C, and I would like to secure the exchanged data with OpenSSL, it's quite new for me and I couldn't find examples on the net...

Could you point out some googd documentation on this matter please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the below links. They should be helpful.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html

Also refer to http://www.openssl.org/docs/

Answer (score 2):

Step1 create create a server certificate with:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -out server.pem -nodes -keyout privkey.pem -subj /CN=localhost
```

Step2 Run the Server

```
openssl s_server -www -ssl3 -cipher AES256-SHA -key privkey.pem
```

Step3 Test the Server

View the Live demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DHF7sdk2nY)