# Where can I find OpenSSL documentation?

Tags: openssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Documentation for a client/server program with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424126/documentation-for-a-client-server-program-with-openssl)

Can any one tell me where I can find OpenSSL API documentation?

[openssl.org](http://www.openssl.org) doesn't explain the API clearly.